# Soma de varios arquivos de texto *.txt

Tags: txt

Tenho uma serie de arquivos em .txt e gostaria de soma-los / juntar todos num só (Independente da ordem).

É possível fazer isso pelo vba do word, algum outro editor de texto, ou outros meios?

[image: textos]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira relativamente simples é usar o CMD do Windows.

### Usando `for` + `type`:

```
cd /d c:\caminho\para\a\pasta 
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> amalgama.out
```

no lugar de `amalgama.out` você põe o nome desejado de saída.

Não precisa nem fazer um `.bat`, basta executar direto no *prompt* de comando.

**Informação relevante:** eu usei `.out` na saída para evitar que haja dupla concatenação (adicionar o `amalgama.txt` nele mesmo). Qualquer extensão diferente de `.txt` serve, mas convém usar uma que não seja "escondida" pelo Windows. Nada que um `rename` não resolva ao final ;)

### Usando `copy`:

Esta é uma alternativa mais simples, mas não força quebras de linha ao fim de cada arquivo. Pode acontecer de "colar" duas linhas se a última de algum arquivo não terminar com quebra.

```
cd /d c:\caminho\para\a\pasta 
copy /b *.txt amalgama.out
```

O `/b` indica "binário", mas pode ser usado com `.txt`s normalmente, para ignorar qualquer caractere especial.

De curiosidade, o `/d` usado nos comandos `cd` acima serve para mudar de unidade se necessário, evitando executar `cd c:` e `cd \caminho` separadamente, caso o *prompt* não esteja aberto já na unidade correta.

Comment: Funcionou. perfeito! obrigado!

Comment: O `/d` no `cd` não sabia! Sempre forçava entrar na unidade vlw @Bacco